# Nbclust Kmeans Error more cluster centers than distinct data points

Tags: r

I get an error in Nbclust (method = "kmeans") when I want to predict the number of clusters in the binary matrix with 3120 observations and 40 variable.Matrix dimensions are:

```
size(mtrx)
3120 40
class(mtrx)
'matrix'
```

Code line is:

```
number_of_clusters<-NbClust(data=mtrx, diss=NULL, distance = "euclidean",
                            min.nc=2, max.nc=1600, method = "kmeans",
                            index = "alllong")
```

Error message is:

```
Error in kmeans(jeu, max_nc): more cluster centers than distinct data points.
```

Error is still present when I use `distance = "binary"`.
Error doesn't appear if I select any other method type.

I am a little bit confused here. I thought that `max.nc` should be `3119`.
Any help?

**EDIT:**
**This error is not related to the NbClust package, it comes from the kmeans function.** The clue is in the word "**distinct**", and it's funny but I didn't get that part. I guess a picture can tell more then words. So here it goes:

Let's start with the correct approach. In this case I have a data set with at least 3 **distinct** rows, and I am asking for 3 initial centers in the kmeans:

```
Vector<-c(2,2,2,2,2,2,20,10,500,300,400,2)
MATRIX<-matrix(Vector,nrow=4,ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
print(MATRIX)
km<-kmeans(MATRIX,centers=3)  
    [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   2    2    2
[2,]   2    2    2
[3,]  20   10  500
[4,] 300  400    2
```

No error, everything is OK.

Now, lets go through the data set with <3 **distinct** rows:

```
Vector<-c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,500,300,400)
MATRIX<-matrix(Vector,nrow=4,ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
print(MATRIX)
km<-kmeans(MATRIX,centers=3) 
    [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   2    2    2
[2,]   2    2    2
[3,]   2    2    2
[4,] 500  300  400
Error in kmeans(MATRIX, centers=3):
  more cluster centers than distinct data points.
```

The error is obvious now, I have 2 distinct rows and I am asking for 3 initial center.

Hope this will help someone!